# Applying function to Lists

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have the following code:

```
test[xx_, digits_: 17] := If[xx >= 1,
    ToString@Row@Insert[#1, ".", #2 + 1] & @@ 
   RealDigits[xx, 2, digits], 
  ToString@Row@
    Join[{0}, 
     Insert[Join[
       ConstantArray[0, Abs[RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[2]]]], 
       RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[1]]], ".", 1]]]
```

and I am trying to apply it to a list. For example this one:

```
s={0.67,0.89,0.70,0.78,0.54}
```

I can't seem to find a way to make all the numbers in the string into binary and merge them together without any "." Would Appreciate the help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135363/discussion-on-question-by-gio23-applying-function-to-lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### **Edit 4: Lists of lists of lists etc**

Again, the function remains as it was.

```
test2[xx_, digits_: 17] := 
 If[xx >= 1, ToString@Row@RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[1]], 
  ToString@Row@
    Join[ConstantArray[0, Abs[RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[2]]]], 
     RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[1]]]]
Map[test2, list, {Length@Dimensions@list}]

yy := Map[test2, list, {Length@Dimensions@list}];

list = {{0.31, 0.27, 0.52, 0.81}, {0.24, 0.54, 0.62, 0.91}};

yy
```

> [image: nestv1]

```
list = {{{0.805097, 0.756672, 0.481262}, {0.324827, 0.372847, 
     0.267585}}, {{0.140558, 0.0525333, 0.627223}, {0.838575, 
     0.342321, 0.301247}}};

yy
```

> [image: nestv2]

---

### **Edit 3: Application on a nested list**

```
list = {{0.31, 0.27, 0.52, 0.81}, {0.24, 0.54, 0.62, 0.91}};

test2[xx_, digits_: 17] := 
 If[xx >= 1, ToString@Row@RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[1]], 
  ToString@Row@
    Join[ConstantArray[0, Abs[RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[2]]]], 
     RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[1]]]]

Map[test2, list, {2}]
```

> [image: nest]

---

### **Edit 2: Addressing the last comment**

```
FromDigits@
 Flatten[IntegerDigits /@ 
   Flatten@ToExpression@
     StringSplit[test2 /@ {0.67, 0.89, 0.70, 0.78, 0.54}, ","]]
```

> [image: final]

### **Edit: Addressing the comment under the OP**

The updated command should be written as

```
test2[xx_, digits_: 17] := 
 If[xx >= 1, ToString@Row@RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[1]], 
  ToString@Row@
    Join[ConstantArray[0, Abs[RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[2]]]], 
     RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[1]]]]
```

which just gives the `0` and `1` without any decimals and whilst neglecting the first zero in cases that the number we transform to binary is less than one as indicated in the comment.

Quick check

```
test2 /@ {0.23, 1.4, 2.34, 0.67}
BaseForm[{0.23, 1.4, 2.34, 0.67}, 2]
```

> [image: tt21]
>
> [image: tt22]

---

### **Original answer**

With

```
test[xx_, digits_: 17] := If[xx >= 1,
    ToString@Row@Insert[#1, ".", #2 + 1] & @@ 
   RealDigits[xx, 2, digits], 
  ToString@Row@
    Join[{0}, 
     Insert[Join[
       ConstantArray[0, Abs[RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[2]]]], 
       RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[1]]], ".", 1]]]

test /@ {0.23, 1.4, 2.34, 0.67}
```

> [image: output]

Your specific list

```
test /@ {0.67, 0.89, 0.70, 0.78, 0.54}
```

> [image: out2]

Comment: Hi, again.. Is their a way to apply this to nested lists. Ive been trying to apply with a whole bunch of functions but not working

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to concatenate all the elements:

```
s = {0.67, 0.89, 0.70, 0.78, 0.54};
digs = RealDigits[#, 2] & /@ s;
outList = Flatten[digs[[All, 1]]]
```

digs is all the binary digits in all the elements of s and outList concatentates them all into one big list. This may be a better form for your problem than turning them into one big binary number, but if you need to do that:

```
ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString[#] & /@ outList]]
```

1010101110000101000111101011100001010001111010111000111100011110101110
0001010001111010111000010100011110111011001100110011001100110011001100
1100110011001100110110001111010111000010100011110101110000101000111101
1010001010001111010111000010100011110101110000101001000

Comment: Very nicely done!